# xmlrpc apache - How to default handler

Tags: apache, xml-rpc

I'm developing an xmlrpc server using the ws-xmlrpc api implementation from apache.

The xml request I'm going to receive is samething like that:

```
<methodCall><methodName>add</methodName><params><param>
```

As you can see, no handler is specified in the request, for example "Calculator.add".

I need to find a way to add default handler to the server so that requests with method name "add" will be managed by the handler "Calculator".

Thanks in advance

Leonardo

Comment: You should select an answer if one was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your handler with the name "$default", then you don't need the "handlerName." in the method call.

See http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/xmlrpc2/server.html, under "XML-RPC Handler Objects"

Answer (score 0):

The below is the best method to achive it. While adding handler mapping use this class instead of default one.

public class MyHandlerMapping extends PropertyHandlerMapping {

```
@Override
public XmlRpcHandler getHandler(String pHandlerName)
        throws XmlRpcNoSuchHandlerException, XmlRpcException {

    XmlRpcHandler result = null;

    try {
        result = super.getHandler("Calculator." + pHandlerName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out
                .println("Ignoring ALL exceptions so that default one will also get executed");
    }   

    if (result == null) {
        if ((result = super.getHandler(pHandlerName)) == null)
            throw new XmlRpcNoSuchHandlerException("No such handler: "
                    + pHandlerName);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}